# index.css vs. App.css in default app created by "create-react-app" -- what's the difference?

Tags: reactjs

It seems like index.css would be more for global styles and App.css would be for the App component only - but isn't the App component normally also my whole app? What's the best practice here?

Answer (score 47):

The App component is essentially the top most component in a React-based application, from whom all other components are children of. So in create-react-app, the reason why there's an App.css and an index.css is just so that create-react-app can have a very simple directory structure and no naming conflicts between "App.css" and "index.css", so you spend less time removing generic stuff and more time building your stuff instead. The best practice for structuring a React-based app is to just have each component in it's own separate directory with its own index.js file, index.css file and something like index.test.js or however you want to structure your test files. "Index.js" is the first file looked for in a directory when you call an ES6 import statement for that directory, so you can write:

```
import HUD from './HUD'
```

instead of:

```
import HUD from './HUD/HUD.js'
```

So using index.css just helps to make clear that *this* index.css file is for *this* Component, since *this* index.js only refers to *this* Component

Here's a basic React application directory structure:

```
src
├── App
│   ├── HUD
│   │   ├── index.css
│   │   ├── index.js
│   │   └── index.test.js
│   ├── index.css
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── index.test.js
│   ├── Maze
│   │   ├── index.css
│   │   ├── index.js
│   │   └── index.test.js
│   ├── Tile
│   │   ├── index.css
│   │   ├── index.js
│   │   └── index.test.js
│   └── TouchControl
│       ├── index.css
│       ├── index.js
│       └── index.test.js
├── index.css
└── index.js
```

A src level index.css file would be a good place to put top-level container DOM element CSS style rules, since the src level index.js is the initial place in a React-based application where you tell React to physically mount the App Component to the actual HTML DOM, on a container element, something like this and say that 'root' is an ID of an element already on the page before your JavaScript loads:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './App'
import './index.css'

ReactDOM.render( <App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: @MiXT4PE I think src/index.css gets applied globally, doesn't it? At least, this is what I understood from https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2720

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisBeauchamp I had trouble with this as well. Out of the box this is correct but you can change it by changing the import within the index.js. Whatever is imported there is applied globally.

Comment: Hey Stephen, can you please recommend some github repositories that follow the react app structure that you just showed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: First of all just remove all trash files which cra created and implement your own structure .