# What's the difference between index.css and App.css?

Tags: css, reactjs

I usually define global styles in index.css. What is the best practice to define global style? When should I put it in index.css vs App.css when I work on React app?

Comment: You should write global CSS in App.css. It is the root/top component that loaded first and loads all the CSS which is written in it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [index.css vs. App.css in default app created by "create-react-app" -- what's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44484907/index-css-vs-app-css-in-default-app-created-by-create-react-app-whats-the)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a React app, the best practice is to put every component in its own directory containing its corresponding JS and CSS files. The App component is the topmost component in a React app for wrapping all components. There aren't any predefined rules for using `App.css` or `index.css` for global CSS.

Check out this article for React styling best practices: https://medium.com/the-non-traditional-developer/styling-best-practices-using-react-c37b96b8be9c

Relevant question: [index.css vs. App.css in default app created by "create-react-app" -- what's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44484907/index-css-vs-app-css-in-default-app-created-by-create-react-app-whats-the)